# Installation of Symphony on Windows 8.1 using mingw

Tags: mingw, clp

I am trying to link coin-or symphony to Scilab. I have done it for Linux. Now I am trying to build it in Windows I have tried it with MS Visual Studio 2010 but it only generates static libraries (*.lib) files. I want to generate dll files. I tried to build it using mingw but following error was coming in Clp. [Error shown in the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63li4.png)

Comment: Could you perhaps copy the error text in here so it's easier for people to see what the exact error is (also for future reference) ?

Comment: The last line is the screen-shot of the error. Do you want me to add the log also?

Comment: Just adding the relevant logs will probably help. I'm not an expert in this field and was just trying to get the chances for an answer up, having the logs here makes it a better quality post, people won't have to switch sites and are not dependent on the image being hosted.